# MS Access Create Table with Autoincrement and default date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I try to create MS Access Table with autoincrement ID and Default Date field, but next query always says "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.":

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    [ID] AUTOINCREMENT,
    [Email] TEXT(255),
    [ProductID] NUMBER,
    [DateCreate] DATETIME,
    [DateSend] DATETIME
);


ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER [DateSend] DATETIME DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL;
```

Who can help me to fix that query. Thanks!

Comment: And the `ALTER` statement: `ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN [DateSend] ...`

Comment: Which [ANSI Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx) are you in? Much of the Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) SQL DDL is not supported in ANSI-89 (a.k.a. "traditional") Query Mode. If you are using MS Access 2003 or above you can put the Access UI into ANSI-92 Query Mode, otherwise try using an ADO connection (e.g CurrentProject.Connection in the Access object model) because ADO always uses ANSI-92 Query Mode.

Comment: Running Access in SQL 92 mode can lead to all sorts of compatibility problems, including breaking a working application (e.g., different reserved words, as well as AutoComplete on combo boxes with hidden first column stops working).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many `NUMBER` types in Ms-Access, so you have to be specific. I guess you want `Integer`.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    [ID] AUTOINCREMENT,
    [Email] TEXT(255),
    [ProductID] INTEGER,
    [DateCreate] DATETIME,
    [DateSend] DATETIME
);
```

The `ALTER TABLE` syntax requires `ALTER COLUMN` :

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN
    [DateSend] DATETIME DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL;
```

---

You could also have those two in one statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    [ID] AUTOINCREMENT,
    [Email] TEXT(255),
    [ProductID] INTEGER,
    [DateCreate] DATETIME,
    [DateSend] DATETIME DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
);
```

---

It's best practise to have a `PRIMARY KEY` on every table, and you probably intended that for the `ID`:

```
    [ID] AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

---

A page with a lot of useful information about how to handle Access with SQL:

**[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)**

Comment: "There are many NUMBER types in Ms-Access, so you have to be specific" -- did you read the "page with a lot of useful information" you linked to? It tells you that `NUMBER` is a synonym for `FLOAT` i.e. it is specific.

Comment: @onedaywhen: OK, I deserved that totally!

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Tblcontact
(
contactid AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
firstname CHAR (60),
lastname CHAR (60),
email VARCHAR (75)
);
```