# Syntax Error MS-Access query in VB (but not in Ms Access)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to create a table programmatically through Visual Basic (visual basic studio 2008 .net framework 3.5) for a MS-Access database.

I am using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE DatosFTP (
  id AUTOINCREMENT,
  direccion TEXT,
  usuario VARCHAR(30),
  password VARCHAR(30),
  passwordBD TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

But it launchs me the following exception: "Syntax error in field definition"

However, if I execute this query in MS Access (the program), it works perfectly.

Does anyone know what can it be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**password** is probably a **reserved** word.

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE DatosFTP (
  id AUTOINCREMENT,
  direccion TEXT,
  usuario VARCHAR(30),
  [password] VARCHAR(30),
  passwordBD TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

[**Reserved Words**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738)

Comment: @pankeel refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000278/ms-access-create-table-with-autoincrement-and-default-date

Answer (score 1):

`password` is a [**reserved**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) word.

```
CREATE TABLE DatosFTP (
  id AUTOINCREMENT,
  direccion TEXT,
  usuario VARCHAR(30),
  [password] VARCHAR(30),
  passwordBD TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Comment: There is no need of Int datatype in id