# How to fix end of statement when trying to insert multiple values in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2016

I just started a database course that is going over SQL using Access 2016.  I am getting a End of statement error and I am unsure how to fix it.

My table code is `

```
Create Table Pet_Owner (
OwnerID autoincrement Null,
OwnerLastName Char(30) Not Null,
OwnerFirstName Char(30) Not Null,
OwnerPhone Int Null,
OwnerEmail VarChar(100) Not Null Unique,
Constraint Pet_Owner_PK Primary Key(OwnerID)
);
```

and the insert query I have so far that I am trying to add is

```
Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail) Values (
'Downs' , 'Marsha' , '555-537-8765' , 'Marsha.downs@somewhere.com') 
Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail) Values (
'James' , 'Richard' , '555-537-7654' , 'Richard.James@somewhere.com') 
Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail) Values (
'Frier' , 'Liz' , '555-537-6543' , 'Liz.Frier@somewhere.com') 
Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerEmail) Values (
'Trent', 'Miles', 'Miles.Trent@somewhere.com') ;
```

When I use append, it is saying I am missing a semicolon at the end of the first set of values, but if i add that then it says i have characters at the end of my statement. If anyone can help me out or point me into the right direction to solve the error I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Access does support [`AUTOINCREMENT` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000332/1422451).

Comment: Why are you declaring `OwnerPhone` as a numeric datatype? A text datatype would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert query includes 4 `INSERT ... VALUES` statements.  So when you attempt to run that query, you're asking Access to execute a batch of statements.  However Access will not execute batched statements.  You must execute them separately.

And when you execute them one at a time, you will discover another 2 problems:

1. `OwnerPhone Int Null` will not accept a text value such as '555-537-8765';  Make that a text instead of numeric type field.
2. The second insert statement does not include the `INTO` keyword.

I used this statement to create the table:

```sql
Create Table Pet_Owner (
OwnerID autoincrement Primary Key,
OwnerLastName Char(30) Not Null,
OwnerFirstName Char(30) Not Null,
OwnerPhone VarChar(12) Null,
OwnerEmail VarChar(100) Not Null Unique
);
```

(`OwnerPhone` was the critical change.  I changed the primary key assignment just to show you a different method for that.)

Then processed each insert statement separately by loading it into a variable, `strInsert`, and executing it like this:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

That approach successfully added 4 rows to the `Pet_Owner` table.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations since this is literally my first time. It took longer but separating them out worked. Again thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's a shame the error message doesn't give you a better explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to start each statement with `insert into`, and separate them with `;`.

```
Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail)
Values ('Downs' , 'Marsha' , '555-537-8765' , 'Marsha.downs@somewhere.com');

Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail) 
Values ('James' , 'Richard' , '555-537-7654' , 'Richard.James@somewhere.com');

Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerPhone, OwnerEmail)
Values ('Frier' , 'Liz' , '555-537-6543' , 'Liz.Frier@somewhere.com');

Insert Into Pet_Owner (OwnerLastName, OwnerFirstName, OwnerEmail) 
Values ('Trent', 'Miles', 'Miles.Trent@somewhere.com');
```