# I am very new to SQL and Access. I have all these statements to create tables but I get either syntax error or "Cannot find table or constraint

Tags: sql, ms-access

As the title suggests, I am having issues creating these two tables. The other two that I made I had no issue with. I am very new to SQL and trying to teach myself so I am sorry for my ignorance but it is driving me crazy. I am using MS Access 2016

Table 1 (syntax error):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
studentID INTEGER,
firstName varchar(20),
lastName varchar(20),
gender char(1),
majorDept integer,
class varchar(10),
GPA NUMBER(3,2),
PRIMARY KEY(studentID),
FOREIGN key (majorDept) REFERENCES Department(deptID),
check(gender in ('M', 'F')),
check(class IN ('Freshman','Sophomore','Junior','Senior')),
CHECK (GPA >=0.00 AND GPA <=4.00));
```

Table 2 (table/constraint error):

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment(
studentID INTEGER,
courseID integer,
PRIMARY key(studentID),
FOREIGN KEY(studentID) REFERENCES STUDENT(studentID),
FOREIGN KEY(courseID) REFERENCES Course(CourseID));
```

Comment: Why are you even using SQL to build tables? Use Access table designer. Did you use VARCHAR in the successful SQL?

Comment: The error seems to be using NUMBER as data type.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql#:~:text=Syntax%20%20%20%20Part%20%20%20,and%20B%20...%20%202%20more%20rows%20. I used DOUBLE instead of NUMBER(3,2) and now it errors on check(). Where are you getting your SQL syntax? Not all SQL are created alike.

Comment: In the first SQL, I changed NUMBER(3,2) to double and removed the 3 check lines. Then query works. The second runs without changes.

Comment: Another reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000278/ms-access-create-table-with-autoincrement-and-default-date

Comment: I am guessing Access SQL engine does not recognize Check().

Answer (score 0):

The first error is called by declaring `GPA NUMBER(3,2)`, as `NUMBER` is not a data type in SQL. Changing this to `NUMERIC(3,2)` or `DECIMAL(3,2)` will solve this problem. The second error is pulling because you are trying to create a `FOREIGN KEY` on the `STUDENT` table, which doesn't exist because of the first error.